# MongoDB aggregation error $in needs an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is my document and I want to filter all those zipcode along with their corresponding `res_count` that are also present in the array called `data`.

**Document :**

```
{ "data" : [ "10451", "10458", "10467", "10461", "10462" ] }
{ "zipcode" : "10470", "res_count" : 8 }
{ "zipcode" : "10454", "res_count" : 10 }
{ "zipcode" : "10466", "res_count" : 11 }
{ "zipcode" : "10455", "res_count" : 9 }
{ "zipcode" : "10462", "res_count" : 29 }
{ "zipcode" : "10461", "res_count" : 25 }
{ "zipcode" : "10467", "res_count" : 15 }
{ "zipcode" : "10465", "res_count" : 28 }
{ "zipcode" : "10452", "res_count" : 11 }
{ "zipcode" : "10469", "res_count" : 10 }
{ "zipcode" : "10459", "res_count" : 7 }
{ "zipcode" : "10457", "res_count" : 14 }
{ "zipcode" : "10451", "res_count" : 68 }
{ "zipcode" : "10463", "res_count" : 28 }
{ "zipcode" : "10458", "res_count" : 34 }
{ "zipcode" : "10468", "res_count" : 12 }
{ "zipcode" : "10475", "res_count" : 14 }
{ "zipcode" : "10474", "res_count" : 10 }
{ "zipcode" : "10473", "res_count" : 3 }
```

I tried using `$in` but it says `"errmsg" : "$in needs an array"`

Comment: Can you share the full query syntax you are using.

Comment: Actually the above document is not the original document. Its the resultant document that I got from running different query using $facets and then combining them. I just need to access $data in $in to filter out the matching zipcode

Comment: @anonymous : Did it work or still having issues ?

Comment: @anonymous : Please mark it as accepted that way your question will be complete with a working answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  db.find(
       { zipcode: { $in: [ "10451", "10458", "10467", "10461", "10462" ] } }
    )
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've `data` field in just one document. So if you run `$in` in `$match` something like `{$match : {$in : ['$zipcode', '$data']}}` it would throw same error `"errmsg" : "$in needs an array"`.

**But why ?**

In general, [Aggregation pipeline stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) do operations on collections documents treating each document atomically, So you cannot use fields of one document over other documents. (**Ex:-** If you try `$addFields`to add a new field 'dataCopy' taken from `$data` - addFields would not add any new field to docs where 'data' field doesn't exists). So in order to do this operation you need to bring all documents in your collection to one document using `$group`, Try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Iterate on all docs & push document which has 'data' field into 'dataDoc' &
   * push all other docs into 'allDocs' array field
   */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      dataDoc: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: "$data" }, "array"] }, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      },
      allDocs: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: [{ $type: "$zipcode" }, "string"] },
            "$$ROOT",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /** Unwind dataDoc array to make it 'dataDoc' field of type object */
  {
    $unwind: "$dataDoc"
  },
  /** Re-create 'allDocs' array field with objects which meet required condition,
   * newly formed array will have docs whose zipcode exists in data array
   * */
  {
    $addFields: {
      allDocs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$allDocs",
          cond: { $in: ["$$this.zipcode", "$dataDoc.data"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /** Unwind 'allDocs' array */
  {
    $unwind: "$allDocs"
  },
  /** Make 'allDocs' object field as new root, after this your result will have docs
   * whose zipcode exists in data array
   */
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$allDocs"
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uKyX8H8ujCr)